# Maven Assembly plugin. Any way to unzip/untar an archive straight from the descriptor file, rather than relying on antrun plugin?

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I'm using maven assembly plugin version 2.2.1 to build a package in a custom, proprietary format.
As a part of this process, I need to extract a bunch of *external* archives (by external I mean they are not listed as maven dependencies, but they are arbitrary files on the filesystem).

Do you know if maven assembly is able to do that ? I've looked and apparently, it is able to extract a bunch of *dependencies* in an arbitrary folder, but it is unable to extract an external archive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `<unpack>true</unpack>` in your `<dependencySet>` is the way to go.

External archives are not supported by Maven. So you will need to attach them using, e.g. `build-helper:attach-artifact` then you can reference it via the `<dependencySet>`

## Update

One of the comments wanted to know how you could avoid installing the attached artifact into the maven repository (local/remote)

The solution to that is to use a dummy module that is a non-transitive dependency.

We are relying on the assembly being built not being used as a transitive dependency.

So you start with a dummy module, which will look a little something like

```
<project>
  ...
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  ...
  <properties>
    <maven.deploy.skip>true</maven.deploy.skip>
    <maven.install.skip>true</maven.install.skip>
    <!-- or you could override the plugin configuration for a safer - but less quick - solution -->
  </properties>
  ...
</project>
```

That dummy module can attach the files using `build-helper:attach-artifacts`

The your assembly module will just list the dependencies with `<scope>provided</scope>` and `<optional>true</optional>` as a guard against becoming transitive dependencies. (not necessary if the assembly is say the installer bundle and will not be consumed by other Maven builds.

And there you go, the compressed content will be streamed from one archive to the other and the raw file will not be copied to the remote repo... *but* you will always need to build the **hack** module in any reactor that builds the assembly.

Comment: Sounds like the way to go. Thanks ! Will check it out and get back to you.

Comment: Is this the right answer?  I think the question only wanted to be able to unpack a zip that wasn't part of the dependencies of the maven project, i.e. it wasn't a maven artifact at all -- part of source?  But attaching the zip to the project will cause it to be installed and deployed to the repositories . . . I don't believe that is the desired effect, unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: Well you have two choices.... the Maven way (i.e. let the assembly plugin work the way it was intended... mandating a dependency from the reactor) or the hack way (i.e. using antrun or similar to unpack it for you).  If you want to stream the content from one archive to another you cannot use the antrun technique, so you have to go the Maven way and have it pulled from either the reactor or a repository. You can cheat by the way... will update the answer with the cheat

Comment: @Stephen Connolly - I have accepted your answer because it punctually answers my question; however, I decided to go with the antrun plugin, as it seems a bit overkill to do it "the Maven way" :) 
Thank you for your time taken to help me out !

Answer (score 1):

"arbitrary files on the filesystem" does not mean much, from maven point of view.

You should be able to run your maven pom from any point "your machine", "the integration server (jenkins...)". Ant is a tool for "home made" build, maven promotes convention over configuration, and reusability.

Therefore, any resources your project depend on should be **either a dependency**, or **somehow included in your project** .

I expect all my projects to be buildable as id, with a simple svn check out. Anything that is not in the project should be downloaded from mvn repositories.

So When I have to write an assembly project, I make sure everything is available in the project, as resources. If not, you can always build a simple project/pom for shared resources, or use some special plugins that do that for you.

Comment: I agree that what I've said makes little sense in terms of Maven perspective on a project.
"Arbitrary files on the filesystem" is a mistake on my side. I have the files in the project. Considering that mvn assembly plugin is already able to copy files which deviate from the standard structure, all I want to achieve is to be able to extract those files before copying.

Comment: Ok, Then I understand. You want to copy the zip in the project, but avoid to manually extract it. I never did this before. I only found one ref to a plugin supposed to do this, but I never tried it myself : http://www.pohlidame.cz/insolvencni-rejstrik/maven-unzip-plugin.html